# How do I calculate surface area of dashboard through integration?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, geometry

How can I calculate surface area of dashboard through integration. I traced the surface using pencil. I can calculate rough area but I want to calculate actual area through integration. The vertical height 230mm is and horizontal length is 253mm. [image]

Comment: ask [math.stackexchange.com/](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you want to CALCULATE the are? Or do you want to FIND the area? There is a difference.

Comment: If you are interested in the exact area regardless of the method to get it, you can simply get hands on a cad program that can "calculate an enclosed area by tracing the boundary". I remember MicroStation can do it, guess AutoCad can as well.

Comment: I want to find the area using integration. I can calculate using any CAD software like solidworks or I can calculate its area by taking smaller pieces area combining them etc. But here I want to find its area through integration only.

Comment: Cut out the shape on paper then use a precision scale to get the weight of the paper, then do same for full sheet. Area is now weight of cutout/weight of full sheet *height of full sheet * width full of sheet. Done. If paper is too light for your scale use card etc.

Comment: if you truly want to use integration then you need to know the function of the dasboard. That is a very very much harder problem than integrating the function

Comment: @joojaa Yes I want to use integration. I know it is hard but I will learn and I can relate it with manually calculated area.

Comment: @IbrahimOmer then you need to ask how to turn the shape into a function. Its nothard just a bit nonsenical.

Comment: "I can calculate its area by taking smaller pieces and combing them ... but here I want to find its area through integration only.". Perfect, do that with infinitely many infinitesimally small pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Let the left side curve be defined as function, $\ f(x)$ , and the right side at $x_1$ and the bottom line at $y=0$ and the $y=n\ $ at top .

Then the area is $\int_{0}^{n} f(x)\,dx$

### Edit

As per @r13 comment, I transferred your image to the "DESMOS" app.

By eyeballing it one could fit an ellipse and a rectangular, both of which can be integrated analytically. I would need to have one dimension from you then we can integrate.

.

[image: dashboard]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can show him how to write the equation for the curve, then integrate it over as you have indicated.

Comment: Excellent curve fitting technics.

Comment: Hmmm I did not know Desmos could do that.

Comment: When you take a picture with a camera you get this thing called perspective distortion.

Comment: @joojaa good consideration, but it looks to me like this shot was taken pretty much orthogonally, minimizing distortion

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough data for this to do it analytically. The best thing you can do is approximate between eclipse and rectangular

- area for eclipse approximatino $\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot a\cdot b$
- area for rectangular approximatino $a\cdot b$

where:

- a is 230
- b is 235

In this particular instance if you are interested about area the best thing would be to create a grid and count squares. E.g. something like

[image]

Comment: Good idea! Might want to print that paper out with some coarse grid markings, in order to use photo editing software to compensate for the projection distortion (similar to the correction done when trying to get a good cel-phone image of a printed page). After that it might even be possible to "draw" the outline in photo editing software and have it count pixels in the defined region.

Comment: @PeteW using the pixels is probably what I would have done too. Alternatively, if I really wanted to do and integration I would have used something like im2graph, Plot Digitizer or engauge, to get the data points and then do either curve fitting or numerical integration. I opted for this simple method because I thought it was more appropriate given the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the solid white leftmost shape in your picture with the curved surface.

To obtain an equation for the curve initially do one of two things:

- copy/trace the curve to graph paper, or
- very accurately draw a grid on the stencil you have created.

Regard the lower left corner of the stencil at point (0,0) of a Cartesian co-ordinate system.

For defined values of $x$ measure the corresponding $y$ value and create a table of  $x$ and $y$ values.

Enter the data into a curve fitting program. As an initial trial use a spreadsheet. If the r<sup>2</sup> value for the derived equation of the curve is high, say greater than or equal to 0.95, consider that as being accurate for your purposes and you then have an equation you can try to integrate to find the area of the stencil.

Answer (score 0):

I offer three options:

1. Trace the outline onto 5 mm<sup>2</sup> paper and count all the squares more than half covered.
2. Scan it on an ≥ A3 scanner into a PDF or JPEG, import into a CAD program at 1:1 and trace it out using short line segments for the curve. The CAD program should be able to give you the surface area of the resulting shape.
3. Get the JPEG scan and use some editing program to adjust the contrast to the max to get a black and white image. Upload this to a pixel counter application such as [Pixel Color Counter](https://townsean.github.io/canvas-pixel-color-counter/) (the first one I found) and multiply the result by the square of the DPI (dots per inch) of your scanner. That will give you square inches. To convert to mm<sup>2</sup> multiply that result by 25.4<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to find the area? Because if you are then you should have just said so instead of specifying the method which  may be inapplicable. Integration is not the only way to find area.

Because since there is no equation to integrate then you have to do numerical integration. Which means you have to measure a bunch of vertical points of equal horizontal spacing and use the trapezoidal rule or Simpsons rule or any other number of variants. It is not the appropriate method for your scenario.

Better methods are to weigh a square piece of cardboard of known area, then weigh your cutout.

Or roll a planimeter along your cutout which does the integration for you.

Comment: I guess the GPS can do the measurement too? :)

Comment: @r13 Let me in on your GPS system

Comment: You can get a cheap handheld GPS reader/monitor to get into the system.

Comment: @r13 Not the sub mm resolution you would need to find the area of that cut out.

Comment: I was half-joking. The dashboard obviously is too small for that application, which is getting popular for aerial survey use.